# Suppose $a_n+b_n$ converges. Does $a_n*b_n$ converges also?

Tags: calculus, limits

$a_n, b_n$ - sequences
Suppose $a_n+b_n$ converges. Does $a_n b_n$ converge also?

I tried thinking if I can learn something about $a_n$ and $b_n$ by the assumption $a_n b_n$ converges.
I also tried to develop this equation $|a_n b_n - L| < \epsilon$ assuming it is converging.

I didn't get any bright conclusions.
Will be glad help.

Comment: What does the first "sentence" mean? Certainly those are sequences, not sets.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

$a_n =n, b_n =-n$

$a_n+b_n=0$ but then...

$a_nb_n=-n^2\rightarrow -\infty$

Comment: Well does not $-n^2$ tend to $-\infty$?

Comment: When we are talking about convergence, I think it needs to converges to a real number. A sequences that tends to infinity does not converges

Comment: @Giiovanna: but the question asks if the one converges does the other converge. This answer shows that if one converges, the other need not.

Comment: Yes, indeed. This only shows an example when the product does not converges. But it is really easy to show one that the product does converges. Just take 2 constant sequences. The sum is a constant and so does the product. Then, as we can see, the product can or not converge

Comment: @Manasi : Yes... I meant $-\infty$.. :)

Comment: @clayton : Thank you for the Edit :)

Comment: Is it possible proving it in a more "general" way?

Comment: Or should I stick with a contradict by an example?

Comment: Could you please let me know what are you expecting when you say "general way"

Comment: @Giiovanna: The question is if $a_n+b_n$, does $a_nb_n$ also converge? Certainly, anyone can come up with cases where both converge. However, to negate a false implication, one needs to satisfy the hypotheses (in this case, $a_n+b_n$ converges), yet show that the conclusion is not necessarily true (in this case, $a_nb_n$ does not converge). Finding a pair of sequences for which $a_nb_n$ converges does not apply to the question.

Comment: @Giiovanna If you were asked to prove that `2x` is not equal to `x^2` how would you do that? Then what would you say to the person that says well it's true for `x=2`!

Comment: @Giiovanna : I would comment nothing on your question as I guess you have already got what you are looking for... hope that will suffice..

Comment: @robjohn : Thank you for what you have done :)

Comment: @Cruncher : Thank you for what you have done :D

Comment: My first answer was to the guy that asked if $n^2 \to \infty$ was not convergence (it is not here anymore), and so I told that it is not. I know your answer is correct and I wasn't trying to prove that it is not. It was just one case when it converges to compliment one that it does not. @Cruncher, thank you but I am not stupid and I know how to make a proof of something. I never said that I was trying to prove the proposition doing a particular case.

Answer (score 15):

As shown in Praphulla Koushik's answer
$$
a_n=n, b_n=-n
$$
cancellation is a problem.

However, even if you restrict $a_n,b_n\ge0$ then the answer is no. For example, if
$$
a_n=2+(-1)^n,b_n=3-(-1)^n
$$
then $a_n+b_n=5$ yet $a_nb_n$ oscillates between $4$ and $6$.